# Primefaces tooltip for p:inputNumber

Tags: primefaces, jquery-selectors, tooltip, jsf-2.2

I'm using the Primefaces' tooltip component and I'm looking for the right way to use it with `p:inputNumber` fields.

```
<p:inputNumber id="ctrl" title="Help for inputNumber" />
<p:tooltip id="toolTip"  for="ctrl" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur"/>                 
<p:inputText id="ctrl2"  title="Help for inputText"/>
<p:tooltip id="toolTip2" for="ctrl2" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur"/>
```

The `p:inputText` example is working, the `p:inputNumber` is not. I already found out, that the problem is, that the `p:inputNumber` is rendered as `<input>` nested in a `<span>` tag. The `<span>` tag gets the `id="ctrl"` attribute and the `<input>` an `id="ctrl_input"` attribute.

So I changed the selector for tooltip to `for="@(#ctrl_input)"` and this actually working:

```
<p:inputNumber id="ctrl" title="Help for inputNumber" />
<p:tooltip id="toolTip"  for="@(#ctrl_input)" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur"/>
```

Now my problem is, that I'm using many `p:inputNumber` fields nested in composite components which changes the id of the `<input>` tag, so I cannot stick to the `@(#ctrl_input)` selector. The only way I figured out, was adding a parent `h:panelGroup` and passing its client id through to the `<input>` tag. Then I can select the `<input>` as follows:

```
<h:panelGroup id="ctrlGroup">
    <p:inputNumber id="ctrl3" title="Help for inputNumber" a:tooltipId="#{component.parent.clientId}"/>     
    <p:tooltip id="toolTip3" for="@(input[tooltipId='#{component.parent.clientId}']" showEvent="focus" hideEvent="blur"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

So this is working as well, but is there a more elegant way of selecting the right `<input>`?